# Develop a basic DNS server (in C#)

Tags: c#, dns, udp

I am developing a very basic DNS server for my own purpose. The way I understand it, the DNS server receives UDP packets containing the requested domain name and returns the corresponding IP under some kind of standard form.

There is a [standard library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) for reading/writing UDP packets from/to binary format. But where can I find a C# library for serialising/deserialising DNS requests/responses?

Comment: You can check the following set of NetKit .NET classes that makes the work of DNS servers http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/reviews/netkit-component-for-net/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The open source [ARSoft.Tools.Net](http://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/) library contains a DNS Server component (see [documentation](http://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DNS%20server&referringTitle=Documentation)).

You could use this library directly, or just use the source as a starting point for building your own DNS request serializer.

Comment: The source code from the DNS Server component indeed contains DNS packet parsing code. Thanks!

Comment: The project is now on GitHub https://github.com/alexreinert/ARSoft.Tools.Net

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, I couldn't find a library for C# which handles DNS packet serialization/deserialization, which means it's likely you'll have to roll your own.

Edit: I came across this network packet sniffer project on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/CSNetworkSniffer.aspx) which might have what you need.  Claims to be able to to parse TCP/UDP/DNS

I did find this very helpful site for [TCP/IP](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageGenerationandTransport-2.htm) which has a pretty comprehensive set of pages describing [DNS packet types](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessagingandMessageResourceRecordandMasterFileF.htm) including the [general message format](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageProcessingandGeneralMessageFormat.htm).

There might be some additional help from this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518560/how-can-i-parse-a-udp-packet-in-net) though.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at wikipedia you find a list over all RFC's for the dns protocol, i find rfc's to be the best way to implement a network protocol!

now the dns protocol has rather many rfc's so i dont know if this is the best way to read up on the protocol but you get all the information you need atleast.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Internet_standards

Comment: I did find myself implementing the RFC recommendations before I tried out the ARSoft library. More specifically, I used sections 4.1.1 and following of: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035